# Логгирование в многопоточном приложении ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, asp.net-core, логирование

Есть `.NET Core HostedService` приложение. К нему подключены стандартные логи Microsoft. В моем приложении есть n потоков, которые могут осуществлять логгирование.

**Вопрос:** Нужно ли как-то внутри метода, выполняющемся в отдельном потоке, обеспечивать потокобезопасный доступ во время операции логирования? (например, применять конструкцию lock). Если нужно, то как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Я не совсем понял, что такое "стандартные логи Microsoft", но думаю, что сам логгер должен быть потоко-безопасным. Например Serilog

Comment: @PavelPopov Пока подключил стандартный консольный логгер `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console`. Планирую еще подключать файловый. Да, как раз планировал Serilog

Comment: Я уверен с Serilog потоко-безопасен, так что не стоит переживать. Просто подключите правильно, как описано в его доках

Comment: Вы можетее в консольный лг в качестве параметра выводить Id потока, из которого туда отправилось сообщение - проще будет разобраться в логах потом

Comment: ну Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console безопасен для многопотока... остальное из Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.... скорее всего тоже.